# configure virtual hosts in azure ubuntu to run multiple laravel applications

Tags: php, azure, ubuntu, virtualhost

I have created 2 laravel applications in **/home/azureuser** directory.

I want to run multiple laravel applications on single ubuntu VM. I tried configuring virtual hosts but not able to make it work.

Below is the contents of **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName apitesting.cloudapp.net/demo
        DocumentRoot /home/azureuser/demoapp/public
        <Directory /home/azureuser/demoapp/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV dev
        LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName apitesting.cloudapp.net/quiz
        DocumentRoot /home/azureuser/quizapp/public
        <Directory /home/azureuser/quizapp/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV dev
        LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

Not sure whether the above is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It seem we cannot set the `ServerName` in the URL with a sub path param. As according your requirement, you can leverage the rewrite mod.

First, install apache rewrite mod via command: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`, then restart apache via: `sudo service apache2 restart`.

After that, modify the config file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`, config the directory to the parent folder of your applications:

```
... 
DocumentRoot /home/azureuser
ServerName apitesting.cloudapp.net
<Directory /home/azureuser>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
</Directory>
...
```

Then create a file named `.htaccess` in the root directory of your application, to redirect the incoming requests to your `public` folders, with the content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```